# Forge Tutorial does not return any hub

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to create a basic Forge App that will return the project and model GUIDs for a few of my 360 models.
I downloaded, configured per the directions and ran the sample from GitHub ([Here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels)) however when I log in I'm greeted with an empty list of hubs (despite the app being authorized in my BIM360 account).

[image: View from my app]

When using the [Bim 360 Reports](https://bim360reports.autodesk.io/) however, I do see all my hubs (even without authorizing the app).

[image: View from Bim360Reports]

Any idea what could be causing the sample code provided by Autodesk to fail to return any of my hubs? I can't see any errors in my Visual Studio output.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks Eason Kang for your reply, however I'm confident something else is at play here.

I deleted the apps I had registered on the BIM 360 admin account and started from scratch (with screenshots).

Here is my app on the Forge portal:

[image: Forge app]
You can see its Client ID is `TU6gQp3dw7LD4AuO8Nx45h1hefFAEOrG`.

On the admin B360 account, I created a new integration with that Forge Client ID:
[image: B360 Admin]
[side note, I do not understand the purpose of the account ID provided here, maybe that's the key to my issue?]

As you can see, this newly created app is the only one activated. I do not have any other app allowed, so the Visual Report app has no permission.

[image: App List]

Now on Visual Studio, I changed the `web.config` file to match my Forge app's data.

[image: Visual Studio]

And despite all of that, my app has no access to my hubs while the Visual Reports app can see everything.

[image: Comparison]

So am I doing something very wrong, or is something else going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible to access your hubs without setting the custom integration in your BIM360 Account Admin. You might have provisioned the client id `E4d9h5i4nQhrtQCCDPSctLBSyRcKrQCv` of the [BIM360 Reports](https://bim360reports.autodesk.io/) in your BIM360 Account Admin some days ago, but you forgot it...

[image]

Please follow the instructions here to provision your own client id by creating a custom integration with your client id in your BIM360 Project Admin page.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/manage-access-to-docs/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply @eason-kang! I tried what you suggested but that didn't solve my problem. I edited my original post to provide you with more information, hopefully that could help us pinpoint what is going on with my app.

Comment: Is there any error message showing in your dev console while opening your app via `localhost:3000`? It might throw some error there, so your app cannot get your hubs. Another thing we can do is to follow this instruction to help narrow down the issue: https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2018/05/31/troubleshooting-tips-for-accessing-bim-360-docs-and-account-admin/

Comment: No error when opening my app via `localhost:3000`, and I still don't understand how Visual Reports has access to my hubs without me authorizing it. I did notice that Visual Reports has an extra request for `ClientId` that the app from GitHub does not have. Here are a couple screenshots I took from my browser highlighting that: https://imgur.com/a/ELOO1yE

Comment: I just had a potential epiphany: the hubs were not created by me (company A), I was invited to collaborate on them by another company (company B). Is it possible that company B (the owner of the hubs) authorized Visual Reports making their hubs show up even if I (company A) did not authorize it on my account? And that would explain why their hubs don't show up on my app since they have not authorized it. I will create a sample hub and upload a sample project to it and see if that impacts the behavior of the apps.

Comment: If so, you may need to check that with company B, since the custom integration is BIM360 Hub (account) level setting, not a personal user account.